# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'IPython', but ipython is installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, ipython

I have tried to put this script in the `sitecustomize.py` file, to be able to see colored error messages in visual studio code.

the script:

```py
import sys
from IPython.core.ultratb import ColorTB

sys.excepthook = ColorTB()
```

I got the error message above even though I have used `pip` to install `ipython`.

**EDIT:**

I tried to use `coloredlogs` instead of `ipython` and it showed me the same message again

Comment: have you installed `Jupyter` extension in vscode?  if not, install it and then try again.  I just checked and it works for me.

Comment: @SanV I already have it installed

Comment: just to confirm, did you install the microsoft's official `Jupyter` extension from within the vscode _or_ installed jupyter via pip.  the latter may not work.

Answer (score 1):

The `IPython` module only works inside iPython, not inside any other IDE/Shell/etc.

Comment: tried to use `coloredlogs` instead, and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please use the command "`pip show ipython`" to check the installation location of the module:
(If it does not display the location of the module, it means that the terminal used environment is inconsistent with the selected one.)

[image]

Then find the folder of the module in this python environment, try to delete it, and then reinstall it:

[image]

Run:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reinstall python on my computer. there were multiple versions of it, and because of that there were multiple versions of `pip`